# How to set typeface for application name

Tags: android, apk

I have searched a lot but unable to get how to change font type of application name in home screen. To set font type for Button we can use something like `android:typeface="sans"`. How to do similar thing application name in home screen. **How to set typeface for application name**

Please have a look on the **following image** to know what the exact problem is

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible at all. Have you seen other applications doing this?

Comment: I doesn't mean that if other app have done then only we will try to do.

Comment: I really doubt that it is possible to override the default behavior for this.

Answer (score 0):

The name you marked in above image is Activity name only not application name, which is displayed by your Launcher in Android device.

I think if you written your own launcher then only its possible to modify the font type. For existed launcher we can't modify. I am not telling it is 100% correct, but i think so.

I hope this answer may help you to think about launcher settings if available.

Answer (score 0):

If you want custom look of your app icon, then why is it necessary to change typeface of app icon text ?

Instead do  android:label="" in application/activity tag and create an image icon (logo and name of app with any typeface) which have custom look as you desire, so that in reality, there will be only image as your icon but it will appear like icon and modified text typeface.